# Apply filters from an array in CamanJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, camanjs

I want to store all the filters applied by different buttons and then apply then sequentially on an image. For example, if a user clicks on Brigthness, Noise, Contrast. I want to store these filters and once a user clicks on Apply Filters. I want to apply them all. I tried the following method:

```
Caman('#canvas', img, function () {
     //this.brightness(10).render();
     var filters = ["brightness(10)", "noise(20)"];
     filters.forEach(function (item, index) {
          this.filters(item);
     });
     this.render();
});
```

But this gives me the error `this.filters is not a function`. I can use the commented out line but that will only apply predetermined filters. I want to apply filters based on user selection and I want to apply them all at once when user clicks on apply filters.

Here is a link to the library: http://camanjs.com/examples/

Can anyone please guide me how can I achieve what I want? Let me know if I did not explain the question clearly before downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is showing up because when you use `this` inside `foreach` the value of `this` points the filter array and not caman object Try this

```
Caman('#canvas', img, function () {
     //this.brightness(10).render();
     var that = this;
     var filters = ["brightness(10)", "noise(20)"];
     filters.forEach(function (item, index) {
        eval('that.'+item); 
     });
     this.render();
});
```

In above code a copy of `this` is made which is then passes to inside the loop with name as `that`

Comment: Thanks Novice, this seems to be the easiest method for applying the filters. Are there any disadvantages of this method compared to other answers?

Comment: No disadvantage , although you shouldn't use eval in common cases but it's perfectly fine in  frontend cases when you want to make dynamic function calls without compromising code  succinctness in a small snippet

Comment: @NeenaVivek Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

`this.filters` won't work because 'this' refers to the scope of `function(item, index) {...}`

I would do something like this:

```
Caman('#canvas', img, function () {
     // make 'this' available in the scope through 'self' variable
     var self = this;      

     // Filters must hold the function and not a string of the function.
     // so something like:
     var filters = [
       function() { self.brightness(10); },
       function() { self.noise(20); }
     ];

     filters.forEach(function (fn) {
          fn(); // this will execute the anonymous functions in the filters array
     });

     this.render();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define objects in your array and loop over the effects using `forEach()`:

```
Caman('#canvas', img, function () {
  var filters = [
    { name: "brightness", val:10 },
    { name: "noise", val:20 }
  ];
  var that = this;
  filters.forEach(function(effect) {
    that[effect.name](effect.val);
  });
  this.render();
});
```

Comment: When I tried this method, I got the error `Uncaught TypeError: that[effect.name] is not a function`. I tried adding a `.` after `that` but then I got an error about unexpected `[`.

Comment: Make sure `effect` (`item` variable renamed) is passed as parameter to the anonymous function. Or make a jsfiddle with testable code.